# Zend Url and module name case-sensitivity

Tags: zend-framework, routes

I am writing a Zend application.

I am using zend command line tool. I created a couple of modules `Default` and `User` and marked `Default` as the default controller in the application config file. I created respective Index controllers/actions to these two modules too.

When I browse the site root, everything is fine. But when I browse `$site_root$/user`, instead of getting the index controller stuff i get errors.

```
Notice: Undefined index: user in E:\xampp\php\PEAR\Zend\Controller\Dispatcher\Standard.php on line 384

Message: Invalid controller specified (index)
Stack trace:

#0 E:\xampp\php\PEAR\Zend\Controller\Front.php(954): Zend_Controller_Dispatcher_Standard->dispatch(Object(Zend_Controller_Request_Http), Object(Zend_Controller_Response_Http))
#1 E:\xampp\php\PEAR\Zend\Application\Bootstrap\Bootstrap.php(97): Zend_Controller_Front->dispatch()
#2 E:\xampp\php\PEAR\Zend\Application.php(366): Zend_Application_Bootstrap_Bootstrap->run()
#3 E:\xampp\htdocs\$project$\public\index.php(26): Zend_Application->run()
#4 {main}  

Request Parameters:

array (
  'module' => 'user',
  'controller' => 'index',
  'action' => 'index',
)
```

However when I browse `$site_root$/User`, everything is OK again. Apparently the URL has to be case sensitive to reflect the module name. I have thought of some way-around for this like re-writing Zend Request class. But what is the best practice to get lower case module name in URL working?

**Edit 1:** Folder structure:

[image]

Comment: can you show file tree or how you created module and controller and  config maybe would be useful too

Comment: Just change the folder name from 'User' to 'user' in your modules directory.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check the Zend class `Zend_Controller_Request_Abstract`, in file Zend\Controller\Request\Abstract.php. If you have multiple modules in the ZF app, you have to add a `ucfirst()`

```
public function getModuleName()
{
    if (null === $this->_module) {
        $this->_module = $this->getParam($this->getModuleKey());
    }

    return ucfirst($this->_module);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

maybe problem is that you set default module `"Default"` not `"default"`?
Also your folder name should be lowercase but I never used command line so maybe I am wrong.
Rename all modules folders to lowercase.

Answer (score 1):

Depending on OS and Server is probably to have some case requirements.

For example Windows vs linux Paths. On Linux disk Paths are case sensitive and the servers like Apahe path structure is based on disk path. Any operation involved in a basic I/O operation from disk requires to be strict on "file" names.

Also for URLS this depends on Server implementation and probably plugins. For example Apache Http normally is case sensitive but you can enable mod_spelling (http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_speling.html) to make correct spelling in urls like case of works.

Always is a good practice to be strict in your file/class/method/... names. Also appling a pattern (own or no) to be more efficient in your code and structure is recommended.

Comment: In this case, is there any change I can make in the app code (not Zend library) that will make sure that the app runs in any system and not face any issue with case sensitivity? That's really what I am looking for.